# Fault tolerance in Spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2

I am trying to explain about fault tolerance here. Say I have number of  files 1 to 10 in hdfs and spark streaming has read this file. Now my spark streaming has stopped unfortunately. I have files in hdfs say 1 to 20 where 1 to 10 files were already parsed by spark streaming and 11 to 20 were added newly. Now I start spark streaming, I can see files 1- 30. Since I started spark at the time of 21st file in hdfs, My spark styreaming will loose files 11-20. how do I get lost files.
I use fileStream.

Comment: I use fileStream. below is code snippet.val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/home/File")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of fileStream in Spark streaming is to monitor a folder and pick up new files there. So it would only pick up files that are new after the process has started. In order to process files from 11-20, you might have to rename them after the process started.

A better way to handle this scenario is to use messaging queues like Kafka, where you can continue processing streams from any point you like:
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming also provides option for [checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing).
If it is enabled, the process will save checkpoints before start of every batch (in specified folder). Then, if the spark streaming process crashes for some reason, it can be started from the last checkpoint.

```
def createContext(folderName):
    sc = SparkContext(appName='SparkApplication')
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)  # 2 second window

    ## Your stream configuration here

    ssc.checkpoint(folderName)
    return ssc


ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate('/path/to/checkpoint/directory', 
                                   lambda: createContext('/path/to/dir') )
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```